# Filtering Listview not showing correct result when listview item is clicked on Android

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

I'm getting the wrong result when I click on a item from a lisview after the listview data has been filtered. I understand the position value changes when the listview is filtered, I can't work out how I get the right position value.

```
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();
    mAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            getActivityMain().pushNextFragment(FragmentWebview.newInstance(bbcNewsList.get(position).link,"roundfeed",bbcNewsList.get(position).title,bbcNewsList.get(position).source,bbcNewsList.get(position).image));
            System.out.println(" id " + id + " pos " + position);
        }
    });
```

Do I need to use a custom adaptor?

Comment: try to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after filter

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with how your code currently is as there's no way to sync your external list with that of the adapters...especially when filtering is involved. You'll need a custom adapter that instead stores the data type of your `bbcNewsList`. For sake of this answer lets say that `List` is storing `Foo` objects. You'd want to do something like:

```
List<Foo> bbcNewsList;
// Fill bbcNewsList with data

mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),bbcNewsList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//Continue instantiation as needed
```

You could try extending the `ArrayAdapter` for your custom solution but that may be problematic. First you'll need to override the `getView()` method so it knows how to display your custom `Foo` object. Otherwise it'll just convert your `Foo` object to a `String` and display that.  With filtering in the picture, you are stuck with the default logic. In your case, the `ArrayAdapter` would convert your `Foo` object to a `String` and filter based on that result.  You may be fine with that behavior and in which case, you are fine with this approach.  However I will warn that the `ArrayAdapter` has a pretty nasty [filtering bug](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/) if you plan on modifying it on the fly.

Another alternative is to write your own adapter from scratch. Aka implementing the `BaseAdapter` class. While not too daunting, it can be rather challenging for those just learning Android or not sure how adapters work in generally.  This solution would also require you to implement all the filtering code as well.

Finally a third option is use a third party library. I suggest the [AbsArrayAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) class. You'll basically do here what you would with the first option but gives you option of specifying how to filter your `Foo` object. It also doesn't suffer from the filtering bug in Android's `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer, very helpfull i will check out the ABSArrayAdapter. Thanks